# What does search condition mean in the following table constraint?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in oracle that has a constraint with the following attributes:

```
CONSTRAINT_NAME: some name
CONSTRAINT_TYPE: Primary Key
Search Condition:  (null)
```

The issue is that an insertion statement into that table in my code is failing due an exception related to duplicate key exception that the described constraint was violated. What can possibly be the root cause of the issue?

Full ERROR

Handled non-fatal exception org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: PreparedStatementCallBack SQL [INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE (X,Y,Z,D)]; ORA-0001: unique constraint (SOME TABLE) violated nested exception is java.sql.IntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (explained constraint) violated

Comment: Oracle constraints are rules or conditions set at the time of table creation, in order to protect the integrity of the table. In the above case, it might be a Primary key violation i.e. we can't insert a value into the table that already exists. Share the ORA error you see.

Comment: Of course it would help if you were to copy and paste the actual, full, complete error message. But a PK violation is exactly what it says.  A column defined as a Primary Key can have only one row of a given value.  The PK value _uniquely_ identifies the row. You already have a row with a PK value of, say, 'FRED', and you are trying to insert another row for 'FRED'.

Comment: The SEARCH_CONDITION column in [USER|ALL|DBA_CONSTRAINTS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/ALL_CONSTRAINTS.html) is the validation rule to apply for check conditions. It will be null for other types of constraint, such as primary and unique keys. Why do you care though? The error message refers to a duplicate key violation, which seems pretty self-explanatory. Don't insert duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you added the full error since my last response, and it is exactly what I expected - ORA-0001 -  unique constraint (SOME TABLE) violated .  And the answer was also in my previous comment:

A column defined as a Primary Key can have only one row of a given value. The PK value uniquely identifies the row.

You are trying to insert a row with a PK value that already exists in the table.

```
SQL> create table my_test (empid number primary key,
  2                      fname varchar2(10),
  3                      lname varchar2(10)
  4                      )
  5  ;

Table created.

SQL> -- insert with a PK value of 1
SQL> insert into my_test values (1,'Hawkeye','Pierce');

1 row created.

SQL> -- insert another with the same PK value
SQL> insert into my_test values (1,'B.J.','Hunnicut');
insert into my_test values (1,'B.J.','Hunnicut')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCOTT.SYS_C007881) violated


SQL> --
SQL> --
SQL> drop table my_test purge;
```